# Nagios Plugin for showing Temperature Graph and values

Tags: nagios

Firstly install Nagios on your machine with with Mysql server(LAMP on Linux).
Then download the Nagios plugin from this link.
[Nagios Plugin URL](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0Y89BFCSIJ2aHNwVEtHWmZoSU0/view?usp=sharing)

Add the downloaded files in the directory of nagios where you install.
and the code is in the Temperature.php file.just change the database name and table name according to your database info.
the code given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Temprature</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
${demo.css}

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
 table-layout: fixed;
 margin-left:8%;
}
th, td {

padding: 15px;
text-align:center;
}


    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){    

document.getElementById('refresh').innerHTML="Refreshing....";  
  },35000)  

  setTimeout(function(){    
  location = '' 
  },40000)

</script>
    <?PHP
$maxdattemp="Todays";       
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'nagios', 'nagios12345', 'Temperature');
if (!$link) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!$link) {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
if(!isset($_REQUEST['date']))
{
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Temp ORDER BY date DESC , time DESC";
}else
{
$dat=$_REQUEST['date'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM Temp where date='".$dat."' ORDER BY date DESC , time DESC";

}
$arr=array();
$tim=array();
$time=array();
if ($result = mysqli_query($link , $sql)) {


for ($row_no = 0; $row_no <= $result->num_rows - 1; $row_no++) {
$result->data_seek($row_no);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
//echo " centigrade = " . $row['centigrade'] . "\n";
$arr[] = floatval($row['centigrade']);
 $d=strtotime($row['time']);
 $hour = date("H", $d);
 $min = date("i", $d);
 $sec = date("s", $d);
// $tim[]= 
 $tim[]= "'".$row['date']." , ".$hour.":".$min.":".$sec."'";

//echo "Created date is " . date("h:i:sa", $d);
//array_push($tim, $row['time']);
//echo $tim[$row_no];

}
}
}
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Graph'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Temperature'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [<?php echo $temp= implode(",", $tim); ?>],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Centigrade',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' °C'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -40,
        y: 20,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
        shadow: true
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        data: [<?php echo $tempa= implode(",", $arr); ?>]]
    }]
});
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 700px; height: 400px;"></div>
<h3 id="refresh" style="color:#090;margin-left:28%;position:absolute"></h3>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','nagios','nagios12345');
mysql_select_db('Temperature') or die( "Unable to select database");
?>



<table style="width:100% !important; border:none !important;">
<col width="40%" />
<col width="50%" />

<tr>

<td style="border:none !important;position:fixed;top:10px;right:5px"> 
<h3 style="color:#600 ">Latest Temperature Reading:</h3> <?php
$query="SELECT * FROM Temp ORDER BY date DESC , time DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
 if($num_rows>0)
 {
$f1=mysql_result($result,0,"centigrade");
$f2=mysql_result($result,0,"farenheit");
$f3=mysql_result($result,0,"date");
$f4=mysql_result($result,0,"time");
 }
//echo $f1.' C'.' , '.$f2.' F'.' , '.' Time: '.$f4.' Date: '.$f3;
if(isset($_REQUEST['date']))
{
 $dat=$_REQUEST['date'];
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(centigrade) AS cent, MAX(farenheit) AS farh FROM Temp WHERE DATE(date) = '".$dat."'");
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result1);
 if($num_rows>0)
 {
$max=mysql_result($result1,0,"cent");   
$farh=mysql_result($result1,0,"farh");
 }
 $maxtimeresult = mysql_query("SELECT time as tim from Temp WHERE centigrade = '".$max."' AND DATE(date) = '".$dat."' ORDER BY time DESC");
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($maxtimeresult);
 if($num_rows>0)
 {
  $time=mysql_result($maxtimeresult,0,"tim");

 }
  $maxdattemp= $dat;
 }
 else
 {
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(centigrade) AS cent, MAX(farenheit) AS    farh FROM Temp WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result1);
 if($num_rows>0)
 {
$max=mysql_result($result1,0,"cent");   
$farh=mysql_result($result1,0,"farh");
 }
 $maxtimeresult = mysql_query("SELECT time as tim from Temp WHERE centigrade = '".$max."' AND DATE(date) = CURDATE() ORDER BY time DESC");
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($maxtimeresult);
 if($num_rows>0)
 {
 $time=mysql_result($maxtimeresult,0,"tim");
 }
 } ?>
 <h4 style="color:#090">Date: <?php echo $f3 ?></h4>
 <h4 style="color:#090">Time: <?php echo $f4 ?></h4>
 <h3 style="color:#00F"><?php echo $f1 ?> °C</h3>
 <h3 style="color:#00F"><?php echo $f2 ?> °F</h3>
<?PHP
if(mysql_result($result1,0,"cent")){
 ?>
 <h3 style="color:#F00"><?php echo $maxdattemp; ?> Maximum Temperature:</h3>
 <h4 style="color:#090">Time: <?PHP echo $time ?></h4>
 <h3 style="color:#F00"><?php echo round($max, 2);?> °C </h3>
 <h3 style="color:#F00"><?php echo round($farh, 2);?> °F </h3>
 <?PHP }else
 {?>
 <h3 style="color:#F00">Todays Maximum Temprature:</h3>
 <h4 style="color:#090">No Entry for Today</h4>

 <?PHP }?>
 <form  action="Temperature.php" method="post" >
  <input type="hidden" id="All" name="All">
   <input type="submit" value="Show All"> 
 </form><br/>
  <form  action="Temperature.php" method="post"   style="width:30%;right:1%;position:fixed;">
  <span style="color:#090">Select Date:</span>
  <input type="date"  id="date"  name="date"> 
 <input  type="submit"> 
 </form>

  </td>


  </tr>
  </table>

   <br /> <br /> <br /> 
   <table style="width:50%">
   <col width="40%" />
   <col width="40%" />
   <col width="40%" />
    <col width="40%" />
     <tr>
     <th>Centigrade</th>
    <th>Farenheit</th>
    <th>Date </th>
    <th>Time </th>   
     </tr>
    </table>
    <?php


  if(isset($_REQUEST['date']))
  {
 $dat=$_REQUEST['date'];

$query="SELECT * FROM Temp where date='".$dat."' ORDER BY date DESC , time DESC";   
$result=mysql_query($query);


}else{

$query="SELECT * FROM Temp ORDER BY date DESC , time DESC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
}
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
mysql_close();
if(mysql_numrows($result)>0){

$i=0;while ($i < $num) {
$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"centigrade");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"farenheit");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"date");
$f4=mysql_result($result,$i,"time");




  ?>

 <table style="width:50%">
 <col width="40%" />
 <col width="40%" />
 <col width="40%" />
 <col width="40%" />

   <tr>
  <td headers="Centigrade">
  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
 </td>
 <td headers="farenheit">
 <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
 </td>
  <td headers="date">
  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
 </td>
 <td headers="time">
  <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f4; ?></font>
 </td>
 </tr>
  </table>
 <?php $i++;

  }

  }else
{?>

 <h4 style="margin-left:27%"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php      echo 'No Record Found'; ?></font>
 </h4>


 <?PHP 
 }
 ?>



</body>
</html>
```

You will find a side bar on the in Nagios and the option Mysql Report under reports and there is the Graph and the temperature data with latest Temperature Reading and Today's Maximum Temperature.
Thanks!.

Comment: Indent code with four spaces and it gets nice formatting (and colorisation, based on your tags).

Comment: hmm .. .and your question is ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to SSH if your trying to access another localhost.

http://www.sequelpro.com/docs/connecting_to_a_mysql_server_on_a_remote_host

Comment: Xavier U have any idea of arduino or nagios monitoring system..?

Comment: No, I'm familiar with what Arduino can do though. I just know that if you're trying to access a remote local server you should probably SSH to the other computer. If the server is actually hosting sites you should be able to just use the server's name a password.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable remote MySQL access on your mysql server for your other PC and use your MySQL server IP instead of localhost in your scripts.